# Any faster way to append a dict of integer or floating values to a dict of lists

Tags: python-2.7, list, dictionary

In the following code:

1. `eval_key_list` is a list of meaningful strings for users
2. `eval_dict` values are either integers or floats, and are re-computed inside a larger loop
3. `eval_recrod_dict` is a dict of lists

The code:

```
for key in self.eval_key.eval_key_list:
    self.eval_record_dict[key].append(self.eval_dict[key])
```

This append action happens in the end of the calculation loop.
When the program finishes, `eval_record_dict` contains many lists of calculated data.
I found that this data saving operation is quite slow, and it's taking 40% of the loop time.
The following is the output from python profiler of this calculation loop

```
Total time: 1.78099 s
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
   681    189376       336689      1.8     18.9  for key in self.eval_key.eval_key_list:    
   682    186417       382640      2.1     21.5    self.eval_record_dict[key].append(self.eval_dict[key])
```

Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: The way to speed this up is to restructure your data, but there isn't enough information here to suggest a good way to do so.

Comment: I don't see a very time consuming operation here, find a key in dictionary and append in a list is not very time consuming, maybe the problem is with `self.eval_key.eval_key_list`, what is this variable structure?

Comment: @Arman  self.eval_key.eval_key_list is a list of meaningful strings for users

Comment: I found the root cause of the slowness. It's the python profiler that is slowing down everything!